# Right sql solution?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I have a following question with respect to which of the below sql is right for the types of question.

QUESTION 1:

I have two tables: TABLE1 and TABLE2. TABLE1 has 1 million records and contains the variables ID and AGE. AGE is a bucketed variable to the nearest 10-years (e.g. 10, 20, 30, 40…). TABLE2 contains 100 records and has the variables ID and SALARY. ID is unique in each dataset. Below is a SQL query that an analyst wrote. What does this do? How many rows does the resulting table have?

```
SELECT a.ID,a.AGE,b.SALARY 
FROM TABLE1 a LEFT JOIN TABLE2 b ON a.ID=b.ID 
WHERE b.SALARY>50000
```

My first answer:

This query would first create a left join of two tables. Table1 with Table 2. Which means that it would keep all the matching records of both the tables where match is done on Id. And it would also retain all the records from table1. Then it puts a filter on this left join table and selects only those records where salary of the individual is more than 50000.

In terms of no. of records, it would initially have 1MM records when the left join is done. But after the filter it may also have zero records based on how many records actually have salary more than 50000. If no record or Id has salary more than 50000 then it would be having zero record in the end.

Also I believe if I do a.salary like below it should give an error right as salary variable is not present in table 1.

```
SELECT a.ID,a.AGE,b.SALARY 
FROM TABLE1 a LEFT JOIN TABLE2 b ON a.ID=b.ID 
WHERE a.SALARY>50000
```

QUESTION 2: I want to produce a dataset that has all the records from TABLE1 but only joins to TABLE2 where salaries are greater than 50000. How would you “fix” the query?

```
My answer: It should be below: 

SELECT a.ID,a.AGE,b.SALARY 
FROM TABLE1 a LEFT JOIN 
(select Id, Salary from TABLE2 where salary >50000) as  b 
ON a.ID=b.ID
```

This would def. give atleast 1MM records as it first filter and then gives the join.

Is this correct understanding for both?

Comment: "How many rows does the resulting table have?" --> Execute it and see. To only join with rows in the B table where salaries are above 50K, make that part of the join criteria: `ON a.ID = b.ID AND b.Salary > 50000`.

Comment: It seems pointless to generate 1,000,000 rows...if you made it a RIGHT JOIN it would only give the number of records where salary is greater then 50,000. Note: as there might be none then take this parameter out for a moment (ie delete "WHERE b.SALARY>50000") to confirm that any of the rows join, If all the rows in the b table have corresponding id's in the a table then you'll get 100 rows...

Comment: Yes. Its more optimised to make it as and. I am using sql after three years so kind of rusty now and didnt realise I can use AND.

Comment: Btw, a decent optimizer will recognize that query #1 returns NULLs which will be filtered anyway and rewrite the join to an Inner Join before optimization.

Answer (score 1):

These sound like homework questions, but you seem to have made a good attempt to answer them.

The first query returns between 0 and 100 rows.  Why?  Simple.  The `WHERE` clause turns the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`.  In the non-matching rows, `b.SALARY` is `NULL` and fails the `WHERE` condition.  Your answer to the first question is incomplete.

The simplest answer to the second question is to move the condition from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause.  Your answer is also correct, but could potentially confuse the optimizer and produce a less-than-optimal query plan (although not in SQL Server).  In fact, when I first learned `LEFT JOIN`s I used subqueries for this purpose before getting used to the additional conditions in the `ON` clause.

Your answer to the second question is acceptable, but probably not the desired answer.

Comment: You mean the first query returns between 0-1MM?. You mentioned 0-100. So asking if you meant 0-1MM. And yes, we can use and too. I didnt realise that.

Comment: @user . . . No, I think I was quite clear.  Between 0 and 100.  The second table has 100 unique ids matching unique ids in another table.  The `WHERE` clause turns the join operation into an inner join.  Only a maximum of 100 rows could be returned.

Comment: Yes. You are right. Where would do inner and inner upper limit would be 100

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the first question should be between 50 and 100 records. 
My reasoning - When we do a Left Join, the number of records comes down to 100. 
In the 100 records, we know that 100k is the median - which means there are at least 50 records above Salary 50000.
When 50k is the Mean, it means that there are records below 50k as well, and that needs to be taken into account.

Comment: The question doesn't mention anything about median. Left join will result in retaining all the records (1 million) from the left table.